# Making Installation package file in the visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am now using Visual Studio 2012 to make an install package.

The question is, I want to know how to add the uninstall function. So I searched for it on the Internet, and found that I can use the msiexec.exe to make it work.

But my question is, when you uninstall the program, if it is still open while you are uninstalling it, it will not popup a window to inform you to close the existing instance.

How can I do this using Visual Studio 2012?

Comment: Are you using InstallShield Limited Edition?

Comment: I did a couple searches and found many answers based on different app types (win form, WPF, etc). Have you tried googling it?

Comment: I am using the Visual Studio to make the intallation package. I am using the winform, could you put the links here?

Comment: Question says 2012 (twice), but tagged 2010. Which is it? And what technology are you using to build your installation.